# classic asp sorting alphanumeric values from Excel using order by

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I am listing a load of spare parts on a web page which is supplied to me weekly by my supplier. I just upload the .xlsx file to the web folder and the page populates itself. The object is not to change the file in any way so no work is involved. In classic ASP I am using

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};"&_
    "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath(file) & ";" 
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM A1:D10000 order by ""Item number"" ASC"
Set objRS=objConn.Execute(strSQL)
```

Item number is the part number which can be numeric or alphanumeric
the problem is the order is not correct

example

x1
x11
 
x111 
x2
x22
x222

when it should be

x1
x2
x11
x22
x111
x222

I understand why this is happening but can't find a way of getting the order correct

Everything else works really well but customers are not expecting to find X1000 before x200 and it has caused a few problems

Many thanks in advance for any help supplied

Comment: Is it literally always "X" followed by a number, or are you generalizing in your example?

Comment: Sorry just generalizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: updated with my full test code and input/output.
I'm running this in Excel, but I just confirmed it in a simple ASP page...

```
Sub TestQuery()

    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sPath
    Dim sSQL As String

    sSQL = " select [Item Number], [Name] from " & _
           " D22:E34 order by 1*right([Item Number],len([Item Number])-1) "

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name


    oConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" & _
               "DBQ=" & sPath & ";"

    Set oRS = oConn.Execute(sSQL)

    If Not oRS.EOF And Not oRS.BOF Then
        ToSheet Sheet1.Range("H22"), oRS
    Else
        MsgBox "No records found"
    End If

End Sub

Sub ToSheet(rng, rs)
    Dim f, i
    i = 0
    For Each f In rs.Fields
        rng.Offset(0, i).Value = f.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next f
    rng.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried but I get [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: removing the 1* gets rid of the error but order is still wrong :- order by Right([Item number], Len([Item number])-1) ASC

Comment: I can see exactly how you have done it but i still get the error, I will work on it as it must be something stupid my end, many thanks for the help

Comment: Found the problem, I have a few random codes that are different which I had not noticed, over 1800 are just x**** but about 5 are xx**** and ****xx I can't guarantee the codes won't change to something else at another point so need something that removes all letters so sort can be done on just the numbers. Your example though to my brief is 100% spot on :)

Comment: You *could* use a whole bunch of nested `Replace()` calls to remove the alpha characters, and finally convert to Long then sort on that.  Not great though...

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem in Excel, one solution is to split the data into the numeric and alpha portions, using "helper columns", and then sort on the helper columns.

Depending on what your real data looks like, you might use these formulas:

### Alpha (first) section

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A1&"0123456789"))-1)
```

### Numeric (second) section

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A1&"0123456789")),99)
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply, I found this

ORDER BY LEFT([Item Code], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Item Code])-1), -- alphabetical sort
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Item Code], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Item Code]), LEN([Item Code]))) -- numerical

which I belive is the same kind of thing but I couldn't get PATINDEX to work, just gave errors all the time, how would I put your example into a statement like this ?

Regards

Rob

Comment: @RobMatthews I came across that code string also, but I am not at all knowledgeable in that area.  I agree it seems to be the same principal as in Excel, but I am sorry I can't help you get it to work with that statement.

Comment: Thanks for helping